# How to ignore an OPENSSL_ENGINES environment variable in my app?

Tags: c++, openssl, environment-variables

I'm using *openssl* library in my C++ app. I've found out how to ignore an `OPENSSL_CONF` environment variable. It's possible by specifying of my own config file:

```
OPENSSL_config("openssl.cnf");
```

But what about an `OPENSSL_ENGINES` environment variable? How can it's value be ignored in my app? How to prevent loading the engines from this path?

I've a look at *openssl* sources. There is the `OPENSSL_ENGINES` variable reads by default without any conditions.

```
...
if ((load_dir = getenv("OPENSSL_ENGINES")) == 0)
    load_dir = ENGINESDIR;
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSSL does not seem to expose a proper way to ignore that environment variable. As a workaround, you could set that environment variable yourself to some bogus value before invoking `ENGINE_by_id()`, like this:

```
putenv("OPENSSL_ENGINES=/dev/null");
```

You will have to be a little careful that the bogus value you choose does not happen to exist as a valid path on the file system. `/dev/null` could be an option, depending on your environment.